# transparency mood screen change everything look really white illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, gradient, lighting-effects, gradient-mesh

I use illustrator to design lighting shape by make shape gradient black and color then make mood screen from transparency section but it makes everything look really white

Any advises?

[image: the shape is appearing white]

Comment: Mood screen? It doesn't need Illustrator, you can fill the form with a pen http://solaritymentalhealth.com/media/Moodscreen.pdf If you still say it's Illustrator usage problem you should describe what's the goal and what's the fault in your current attempt. Then you should reveal the exact details of the current attempt.

Comment: I have no idea what's being asked here.